# How can I do a XML with optional content with XSLT in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to do a part of a XML with XSLT but Integrator Studio (Eclipse with plugins of WSO2 ESB) mark an error but it doesn't show what is happening.

I have the next xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="a" />
    <xsl:param name="b" />
    <xsl:param name="c" />
    <xsl:param name="d" />
    <xsl:param name="e" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FLD NAM="FILTRO">
            <xsl:if test="string-length($a) > 0">
                [F:AH]BAAA = '<xsl:value-of select="$a" disable-output-escaping="yes" />' & 
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($b) > 0">
                INSTR(1,[F:SQH]SSS,'<xsl:value-of select="$b" disable-output-escaping="yes" />') & 
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($c) > 0">
                [F:AH]BBB>=[<xsl:value-of select="$c" disable-output-escaping="yes" />] &
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($d) > 0">
                [F:AH]AAA<=[<xsl:value-of select="$d" disable-output-escaping="yes" />] &
            </xsl:if>
            find([F:AH]XX,<xsl:value-of select="$e" disable-output-escaping="yes" />)
        </FLD>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to build a XML with only one tag

and the content depend of the params.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier if you posted your input XML, but at first glance you would need to replace your & by &amp; and < by &lt;. Try it here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uN

Comment: @Sebastien I haven't got a input XML, it is a JSON so I use params to get the values. I replace the characters you comment and it disappear  the problem. Thank you, if you add the answer I accept you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I need to replace & and < by &amp ; and &lt ;, like say Sebastien in the comment